# Laravel controller and adding to the result set

Tags: laravel-5

I've checked the Q&A about this and can't find anything, so thought i'd ask.

I have a very simple Laravel controller returning all results from a table as below via the 'Name model'. There is then also a further call to my controller, via the model to count the rows and all works and sends to the result set fine...

```
// All results from my 'Name' model:
$results = $this->name->getAllResults(); // All works fine.

// I then use my controller again, count the rows via the model and add them to $results:
$results['count'] = $this->countNames(); // Again fine
```

BUT, when i try to add a string to the $results array before i pass it off to th view, as in:

```
$results['test'] = 'Test'; // This fails in the view
$results['test'] = 124; // But this passes in the view and renders.
```

It only seems to allow me to add an INT to my result set array. as `$results['test'] = 124` also fails.

I then finally, have this sending to my view via:

```
return view('names', compact('results')); // And that works fine.
```

Can anyone see what it is I am missing and why integer added to $results works and not a string?. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating collection data. The following line will give collection of models.

```
$results = $this->name->getAllResults(); // This may give collection of the model
```

And below, you are updating the collection object.

```
$results['count'] = $this->countNames();
```

You can do the following to safely send data to view, without modifying any.

```
$results = $this->name->getAllResults();
$count = $this->countNames();
$test = 'Test';
$test2 = 124;
return view('names', compact('results','count','test','test2'));
```

Comment: Ah, indeed I can. Thanks very much abid! Upvoted but won't show due to rep, sorry.

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept as answer if it helped.